# Matrix representation of linear operator in 2 dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let V be a 2 dimensional vector space and $T: V \to V$ a linear operator. Let $B = (v, T(v))$ be a basis. Find the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to the basis $B$.

Let $A$ be the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to basis $B$. So $A$ must fulfill $T(B) = BA$. So we have 
$T(B) = (T(v), T(T(v)))$ and also 
$$
BA = (v, T(v)) 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
= 
(a_{11}v + a_{21}T(v), a_{12} v + a_{22} T(v) )
$$
Thus we have
$$
a_{11} v + (a_{21} - 1) T(v) = 0 \\
a_{12} v + a_{22} T(v) - T^2(v) = 0.
$$

The first equation yields $a_{11} = 0$ and $a_{21} = 1$ since $v$ and $T(v)$ are linearly independent. 
Since $(v, T(v))$ are basis vectors we there exists scalars $b_1$ and $b_2$ such that $T^2(v) = b_1 v + b_2 T(v)$. Thus
$$
a_{12} v + a_{22} T(v) - b_1 v - b_2 T(v) = 0
$$
so $a_{12} = \mathbf{b_{1}}$ and $a_{22} = \mathbf{b_2}$. So the matrix representation of $T$ w.r.t. $B$ is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & b_1 \\
1 & b_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
End of proof.

I want to know if I can have a matrix representation not depend on the scalars $b_1$ and $b_2$. Also overall does this proof look correct?